Depth of quadrupole Ion Trap
I working on building quadrupole ion trap(I think it will be linear trap - with 4 electrodes and 2 end-caps), and I try to understand all the equations and the formulas, in order to do a calculation of the depth of the trap.
I very confuse. I know that the potential is determine the depth, but in some cases they talk about the potential and in the other they talk about the pseudopotential. and also, I sew few different terms for the pseudopotential, I think that this difference in the pseudopotential is because each one proper to specific type of trap.
What I was found:
On the 4 electrodes we will apply DC and AC components, and on the end-caps we will apply only DC component. So, there a different potential in the radial axis and the axial axis? or maybe is a combination of this two potential?
I found in this site the next formula of depth:
$$D_{x,y}=\dfrac{Vq_{x,y}}{4}$$
but in this site they talking only about the 2D trap, which is four electrodes without the end-caps. I need also to trap in $z$ direction. So, because they didn't explain how they get this formula, I can't understand if it similar for my case? or maybe how to calculate it for my case with additional of Z trap direction?
how can I do the calculation of adding end-caps electrode with only DC component? how it will influence of the depth? I need to calculate the depth of the axial direction and the radial direction separately? or maybe together?
